# Sybase dblib stored procedure

Tags: sybase, sap-iq, sybase-ase15

I am using Sybase DB and using dblib interface( C++ Interface) to connect and pass commands to Sybase DB.
I have one stored procedure added to Sybase DB. Below is the signature of stored procedure:

**create procedure process_write @id varchar(35), @pTime datetime,@status tinyint**

and I am calling this stored procedure with below :

***process_write '000000100', '22/9/2022 10:18:37', 1***

Now when I run my code I do not see error on console and the stored procedure executes successfully, But when I run this in **isql** command prompt, I get below error:

**Msg 247, Level 16, State 1:
Server 'ABCXYZ', Procedure 'process_write':
Arithmetic overflow during implicit conversion of VARCHAR value '22/9/2022 10:18:37' to a DATETIME field .
(return status = -6)**

I am not able to figure out how this is working in code but failing in isql console?

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**

`ASE` defaults to processing strings of the format `X/Y/Z` as `M/D/Y` and this likely explains why your `isql` session is generating an error (ie, your `isql` session is running with `mdy` as its default `dateformat`).  My guess is that somewhere in your `dblib/C++` code you've either modified the `dateformat` or the `language` used by the `dblib/C++` session which in turn insures your proc call works (ie, no conversion errors are generated).

I don't work with `dblib/C++` so I don't know if you need to modify a db connection attribute or if you just issue a `T-SQL` command upon successful connection, eg:

```
set dateformat 'dmy'
```

---

In Sybase `ASE` when processing strings as dates it's necessary to tell `ASE` the ordering of the date components in strings like `X/Y/Z`.

From a strictly `T-SQL` point of view there are two `set` options that can tell `ASE` how to interpret `X/Y/Z` as a date:

- `set dateformat <format>` - where `<format>` is one of `'mdy'`, `'myd'`, `'ymd'`, `'ydm'`, `'dmy'` and `'dym'`; default is `'mdy'`
- `set languange <language>` - where `<language>` is going to be based on what languages you've loaded into `ASE`; default is `'us_english'` which causes the dateformat to default to `'mdy'` [I don't have details on if/how individual languages may modify the `dateformat` so you would need to run some tests in your environment]

**NOTES:**

- see [T-SQL Users Guide: Date Formats](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_ASE/b65d6a040c4a4709afd93068071b2a76/aa3d19f7bc2b10148022c62f2db8405e.html?locale=en-US) and [Reference Manual: Commands: set](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_ASE/e0d4539d39c34f52ae9ef822c2060077/ab4114ddbc2b1014801ba0f7c01e4e10.html?locale=en-US) for more details.
- to see the current `dateformat` in use for your session: `select get_appcontext('SYS_SESSION','dateformat')`

---

Demonstrating the use of `set dateformat` with a stored proc:

```
create proc testp
@pTime datetime
as
select @pTime
go

-------------

select get_appcontext('SYS_SESSION','dateformat')
go

 ---
 mdy      <<<--- ASE default

exec testp '22/9/2022 10:18:37'
go

Msg 247, Level 16, State 1:
Server 'ASE400', Procedure 'testp':
Arithmetic overflow during implicit conversion of VARCHAR value '22/9/2022 10:18:37' to a DATETIME field .

---------------- 

set dateformat 'dmy'
go

select get_appcontext('SYS_SESSION','dateformat')
go

 ---
 dmy  

exec testp '22/9/2022 10:18:37'
go

 -------------------
 Sep 22 2022 10:18AM
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed explanation. Yes, I analyzed code and found that we were explicitly changing the dateformat to 'dmy' from the default mdy, so did not observe the error while running the application.